# Bash script unrar then rename with dir name

Tags: linux, bash, rename, unrar

I want to rename files in a dir then change the file name base on the dir name this is what I had but it's not quite working

```
    find . -type d | while read dir
do
  cd "$dir"
  find . -name \*.rar -exec unrar x '{}' \;
  find . -name \*.avi -exec mv '{}' "$dir.avi" \;
  cd ..
done
```

root/directory.1.with.rar.in/

root/directory.2.with.rar.in/

root/directory.2.with.rar.in/

root/directory.2.with.rar.in/

root/directory.2.with.rar.in/

I want all the rar in the Directory to be extracted in root then renamed with the name of the directory it was extracted from.

Comment: could you check the filenames are not ending with .rar rather they are ending with .rar.in

Comment: It looks to me like you're basically there, except that the 'mv' statement is executed in the directory $dir; If I'm reading your request correctly, you need to use `find . -name \*.avi -exec mv '{}' "../$dir.avi" \;` instead of `find . -name \*.avi -exec mv '{}' "$dir.avi" \;`. I haven't worked much with rar files; I don't remember if they're capable of containing more than a single file. If so, you will overwrite the first avi file when you move the second.